Removal of manifest file not forcing change in Chrome
We have a website that had a PWA manifest.json file within the website folder and the page HTML also contained the reference to the file
<link rel="manifest" href="/PWA/manifest.json">

We no longer require the functionality so have removed both the  element from the HTML and the manifest.json file from the website folder
We are seeing that people who had previously opened the website in Chrome were still seeing the icon in the address bar to "Open with" (as if the browser had cached the manifest file and the removal has not forced any changes)
Is there a way to force a refresh so that they are no longer seeing this?
People who are visiting the site for the very first time do not see the "Open with" and the website behaves how we desire it to now

Too late. If a PWA is already installed by a user, it is installed and stored locally on the user's system, at least partially.
However, there can be only one way to affect the behavior of the application for the users using their installed instances. The file registered as navigator.serviceWorker on loading of the application window contains initial cached resources used via the "install" listener as a list of file names. You can have some resources installed locally and some obtained from your side used as a source for the installation, and then you can somehow modify some of those files on your site. (If you include absolutely all files used by the application in the initial cached resources, it makes the application 100% off-line.) But your issue description suggests that you did not design this kind of control in the first place property, and now it is too late. Now, only the users who decide to remove the application and install it again can refresh their versions of the application. But you can remove some relevant online resources from your site (for example, by changing the URLs on the application files on your site) and that could potentially render installed application instances defunct unless your application is completely off-line. Perhaps it could force some users to remove the local installation and use your site again. Apparently, this is not quite what you want.
But it looks like you want more than that:

We no longer require the functionality so have removed both the element from the HTML and the manifest.json file from the website folder

This requirement sounds like you require that your application should become non-PWA. You can do it, but not for the users who already installed the application when it was a PWA version. And, come to think about… this is fair enough. You already let the users to install your application. Then the users have every right to keep it as is.
